# Is it possible to control the IP representation when encoding/decoding with json?

Tags: json, go

A [net.IP](https://golang.google.cn/pkg/net/#IP) can have a 16-byte or 4-byte representation. I realised that, even if I have the 4-byte representation of the IP, as soon as I encode/decode with json, I get the 16-byte representation:

```golang
myIP := net.IP{0xa, 0x2a, 0x0, 0x0}
fmt.Printf("This is myIP: %#v\n", myIP)

data, _ := json.Marshal(myIP)

var variable net.IP
json.Unmarshal(data, &myNewIP)

fmt.Printf("%#v\n", myNewIP)
```

The result is:

```
This is myIP: net.IP{0xa, 0x2a, 0x0, 0x0}
net.IP{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xff, 0xff, 0xa, 0x2a, 0x0, 0x0}
```

Is it possible to tell json that I want to keep the 4-byte representation?

Comment: Your decoded IP is the same, just the 16 bytes representation. Call its `To4()` method to get the IPv4 version.

Comment: I did not want to explain the whole problem to simplify the question but let me do it here: I have a struct with a lot of fields. A couple of them are slices of []net.IPNet. At some point, I want to compare two structs. One I get from an http server and it is json encoded. The other one, is in cache. Because of the problem I describe above, any efficient way of comparing structs (e.g. reflect.DeepEqual or hashing the struct), does not work. I could call To4() or To16() but it will mean iterating over the slices, etc. I was looking for a more efficient way to do it

Comment: One clarification: does your server really returns arrays for IP addresses or strings (what we'd call "human-readable" strings such as "127.1.2.3")?

Comment: When an IPv4 address is marshaled, whether it was represented using 4 or 16 bytes is not transmitted (this information is lost). If so, you can't expect unmarshaling to find out the original representation. Unmarshaling will use the 16 bytes representation, and the `IP.Equal()` method will report that they are equal. If you want the original IP and the unmarshaled to be equal by `reflect.DeepEqual()`, make sure the original also uses the 16-byte representation (by calling its `To16()` method).

Comment: Yep, that's what I am doing right now, looping over and `To16()`. I was wondering if there is a way to not lose that information

Comment: @kostix I'm transmitting `net.IPNet` not strings. If they were strings, `reflect.DeepEqual()` would work :)

Comment: You can't change `net.IP`, but you can create your own type, and you can marshal / unmarshal that however you like.

Comment: After all what had been said here, I'd state the problem basically boils down to data normalization. It can be done either on the server side (which creates the presentation of the data) or on the client side. As the client _ideally_ should be resilient to changes in data representations which do not alter the semantics, I'd say it's best to make the client more complicated by implement advanced data processing you sought to avoid 

Comment: Consider using the standard string representation of the IP addresses within your JSON and parsing on the other side with`net.ParseIP`.